# match pattern excluding charactere

Tags: python, regex

i have the following situation.
the character ";" is used as separator but there are some unexpected ";" in the values like *valu;2* or *va;ue4* in this string :

```
...;01;value1;02;valu;2;03;value3;04;va;ue4;....
```

with the pattern `\d\d;.{6};` it returns all the blocks but I would like to know by looping each block and return True/False if **;** is in the value **.{6}**, this way i will obtain 2 lists :

1.these having **;** in the value **.{6}**

2.these not having **;** in the value **.{6}**

the value isn't only alphanumeric, it can accept extra characters (* $ | ) but ; is not allowed in this usecase.

i tried to add [^;] but without success

how can i do ?

Thank you

Comment: What is your question? More specific, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match those that contain no `;` into one capturing group and those that have a `;` into another. Then, you can check the captured group values to see what you actually match.

```js
\d\d;(?:([^;\s]{6});|(\S{6});)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ExHtV/4). Here, `value1` and `value3` are in Group 1, so no `;` is present in those values. `valu;2` and `va;ue4` are in Group 2, so they contain a `;` (as there is a match, and the first group did not match, the group pattern of which is the same except for `;` support).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ozl1fv):

```py
import re
rx = r'\d\d;(?:([^;\s]{6};)|(\S{6};))'
myString = ';01;value1;02;valu;2;03;value3;04;va;ue4;' 
matches = re.findall(rx, myString)
# => [('value1;', ''), ('', 'valu;2;'), ('value3;', ''), ('', 'va;ue4;')]

list1 = [x for x,y in matches if x]
# => ['value1;', 'value3;']

list2 = [y for x,y in matches if y]
# => ['valu;2;', 'va;ue4;']
```

Comment: Thank you **Wiktor Stribizew** 

your regex works and returns 2 groups but i don't really know how to implement using python, maybe with 2 findall...

Comment: @maxashtar All you asked for was about getting two lists, so you just need to add Group 1 to list1 and Group 2 values to list2. See **the edited answer with a Python solution** that I have just added to the answer. One findall call is enough.

Comment: yeah, it works perfectly with one findall, it generates 2 lists, that's i want :)) thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Values without **;** can be obtained with this expression: `\d\d;[^;]{6}`

Values with **;** can be obtained with this expression: `\d\d;(?=[^;]{0,5};).{6}`

Answer (score 0):

It's solved with response of **the fourth bird**, i will use 2nd pattern and loop over list of blocks found with 1st pattern, like this:

```
myString = ';01;value1;02;valu;2;03;value3;04;va;ue4;' 
pattern1 = re.compile(r'\d\d;.{6};')
listOfBlocks = pattern1.findall(myString) 
pattern2 = re.compile(r'\d\d;[^;]{6};')
for block in listOfBlocks : 
    if bool(re.search(pattern2, block )) is True :
         listeOK.append(block) 
    else : 
         listeKO.append(block)
```

Comment: Please move the first sentence to a comment in response to Wiktor. It doesn’t belong in your answer.